# how to use !important in jQuery animate() function

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Please see the jQuery below:

I am really wondering how can I use CSS `!important` for `height` in this code.

```
        $j('#lveis-wrapper_3').animate({
            opacity: 0.0,
            height : 200
        }, 1200);
```

The CSS of `#lveis-wrapper_3` is below :

```
#lveis-wrapper_3
{
    width: 844px !important;
    height: 936px !important;
    margin: 0pt 0pt 10px !important;
    padding: 0pt !important;
    float: none;
}
```

I can not remove `!important` from `height: 936px` for some reasons...
so I want to change that `height` by `animate()` jQuery function - but how?

Comment: Ugh, all those `!important`... Must be a way to reorganize your code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just cannot do this.

As per [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)...

*"All animated properties should be animated to a **single numeric value**... ... most properties that are non-numeric **cannot** be animated using basic jQuery functionality..."*

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

---

I strongly recommend re-examining your need for `!important`.

Comment: Sometimes `!important` is useful. I do not own the HTML code, nor can I request a change. This means I'll have to replace their CSS etc which makes the code unnecessarily longer.

Comment: @Laoujin, in all fairness, I did not say _"never use it"_ or _"do not use it"_.  I merely said that its _"need"_ should be _"re-examined"_.

Answer (score 6):

You can use css transition to make it work, because css transition will work even if the style attribute is changed by $(elem).attr('style', '...');

you use:

## js

```
// the element you want to animate
$(elem).attr('style', 'your_style_with_important');
```

## css

```
elem {
    transition: all 0.2 linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2 linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2 linear;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what the doctor ordered!

Answer (score 1):

I've used something like this:

```js
const selected = $$(yourSelector);

selected .animate({
    height: height,
    width: width
}, {
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'swing',
    queue: false,
    step: (now, fx) => {
        selected[0].style.setProperty(fx.prop, `${fx.now}${fx.unit}`, 'important');
    },
    complete: () => {
        selected[0].style.setProperty('width', `${width}px`, 'important');
        selected[0].style.setProperty('height', `${height}px`, 'important');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, but try this!

Depending on whether it is a DIV, IMG,... you will have to do something like this. This example is in the case of an image:

```
    $j('img#lveis-wrapper_3').animate({
        opacity: 0.0,
        height : 200
    }, 1200);
```

Priorities are defined in CSS with the selector specificity. Your selector specificity for **#id** was **1.0.0**, but adding **img#id** now is **1.0.1**, therefore the priority is higher.

Comment: Pretty sure the `!important` in the stylesheet would override that, no?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Correct, just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to [wrap](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) the selector you want to animate into a `div`, then animate that `div`.
It will no longer be bound by those `!important` rules.

**before:**

```
<div id="lveis-wrapper_3">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

**after:**

```
$j('#lveis-wrapper_3').wrap('<div class="lveis-outer-wrapper_3" />');
$j('#lveis-outer-wrapper_3').animate({
  opacity: 0.0,
  height : 200
}, 1200);
```

**output:**

```
<div id="lveis-outer-wrapper_3">
  <div id="lveis-wrapper_3">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```