# I want to add !important into animate

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css

It is possible to add !important in animate?
I tried adding like that in angular:

```
angular.element(".myClassName").css("margin-left","100px !important");
```

Comment: No...you can't do that and there are numerous posts on this site with explanations and alternatives ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css

Answer (score 0):

We can create a class say

```
.marginleft100px {
     margin-left: 100px !important;
}
```

and we can add this class using addClass(); instead using .css().

Hoping this will work.

Comment: Please refer this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css** for solution.

Comment: we need to use .animate()

Comment: In animate there is only three properties like div.animate({height: 300}, "slow");

Comment: Hope you referred this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931122/how-to-use-important-in-jquery-animate-function). Try those and let me know.